# Программа на C и MASM

Tags: c, masm

Мне нужно написать на С функцию `funcName(int a, int b, int c)`, которая вычисляет значение по формуле `a*b-c` и возвращает его. Потом мне нужно написать функцию на `masm`, которая вызывает эту функцию с аргументами, которые заданы в сегменте данных и возвращает значение, которые вернёт первая функция после её вызова. Функцию, написанную на `masm`, нужно вызвать в main и вывести полученное значение. Я написал программу, но она неправильно выдаёт значение. Например, если `a=10, b=20, c=30`, то она  возвращает `-2089878984`.

Код на C:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

extern "C" 
int __cdecl funcName(int a, int b, int c);

extern "C"
int FUN();


int main()
{ 

    printf("%d", FUN());
    scanf("%d"); 
    return 0; 


} 
extern "C" 
int __cdecl funcName(int a, int b, int c){ 
    int q = a*b-c;
    return q;
}
```

Код на  MASM:

```
.686 
.MODEL C, FLAT
.STACK 
.DATA 
a dw 10
b dw 20
d dw 30
.CODE 

EXTRN funcName : proc
push a
push b
push d
FUN PROC
call funcName
ret
FUN ENDP
END
```

Comment: А почему у вас push за пределами функции (перед ней) ?

Comment: Если вставить в функцию,  то будет выдавать ошибку. Unhandled exception at 0x0014001e in labvpd.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x24a200eb.

Comment: тогда надо запускать под отладчиком и смотреть что происходит. может у вас в ds не тот сегмент данных ...

Comment: Навскидку. 1) Если вы пихаете параметры в стек *перед* меткой `FUN`, то в эту точку код не попадёт никогда, и в `funcName()` придёт мусор 2) после `call funcName` стек надо восстанавливать. Любого из этих пунктов должно хватать для вылета с Access violation.